# Apache rewrite - clean URLs in localhost

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying for the past few hours to write clean URLs in my LAMP machine.

Apache's mod_rewrite is enabled, and I am trying to use an .htaccess file to pass the URL GET parameters to my index.php script which at the time is just a var_dump of _GET.

My current .htaccess is the following (although I've tried quite a few variations of it I found on other answers with no success)

```
RewriteEngine On

#Make sure it's not an actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Make sure its not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

#Rewrite the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/get=$1 [L]
```

When I point my browser to localhost/my_project/test, all I get is a 404 error saying:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /my_project/test was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Apparently I'm missing something obvious here, any help?

Comment: You need `RewriteBase /` too, right after `RewriteEngine On`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things to look for:

1. Make sure .htaccess is enabled
2. Make sure above code is in `my_project` directory.

Then add `RewriteBase` line as well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_project/

#Make sure it's not an actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Make sure its not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#Rewrite the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?get=$1 [L]
```